# Zend PDF: calculating coordinates after rotation

Tags: pdf, zend-framework, rotation, coordinates, draw

Without getting into too many details - I'm getting parameters (x1,x2,y1,y2,a,b,α) from a web tool and I need to generate a PDF document, by using Zend_PDF library which contains green image rotated and positioned properly on the exact coordinates.

[image]

Now, what confuses me is that Zend does not allow elements to be rotated, but instead rotates paper. So, I assume the rotation needs to be done like this

`$page->rotate($x1 + ($x2 - $x1) / 2, $y1 + ($y2 - $y1) / 2, - deg2rad($rotation));`

because we want the center of the image to be the rotation point, and we rotate it in the reverse orientation so the resulting image will get proper rotation.

The tricky part I'm having trouble with is drawing it. With the simple call

`$page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);`

I'm getting the result as displayed on the diagram - the resulting image needs to be translated as well, since (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are not exact coordinates anymore, but I'm not sure how to calculate them? Any ideas?

Comment: Are the (**x1**, **y1**) and (**x2**, **y2**) coordinates the same in your `rotate` and `drawImage` calls? Or is your image just the green rectangle in which case the values for the `drawImage` should be altogether different...

Comment: Yes, they are the same. The $image is a green rectangle, that's also true. I realize that drawImage call gets the wrong coordinates, but I'm not sure how to calculate the right ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP confirmed in a comment that he used the same values for (**x1**,**y1**) and (**X2**,**y2**) in his `rotate` and his `drawImage` calls. It is pretty obvious from his sketches, though, that the coordinates for the latter call must differ.

Fortunately we know from the way the green rectangle is inscribed in the rectangle from (**x1**,**y1**) to (**X2**,**y2**) that it has the same center point as that rectangle. Furthermore, we have the dimensions **a** and **b** of the green rectangle.

Thus, the `drawImage` parameters must be changed to:

```
$page->drawImage($image, $x1 + ($x2 - $x1) / 2 - $a / 2
                       , $y1 + ($y2 - $y1) / 2 - $b / 2
                       , $x1 + ($x2 - $x1) / 2 + $a / 2
                       , $y1 + ($y2 - $y1) / 2 + $b / 2);
```

Comment: Mate, thanks for the response! The solution is almost perfect - the X coordinate is perfect, but the Y still needs to be translated a bit downwards (in the regular unrotated coordinate system). 
Do you perhaps know why and how to translate it? Simply altering y1 and y2 in the drawImage skews the resulting image, because Y axis in the rotated system is the translation in both X and Y in the original system.

Comment: Can you please share the input values and the resulting PDF for a case in which *Y still needs to be translated a bit* for analysis?

Comment: That been said... @Relja *Simply altering y1 and y2 in the drawImage skews the resulting image* - alter the y values for both the rotate and the drawImage.

Comment: @Relja does it work now as hoped or do you still need help?